# No PlaceholderFragment class in MainActivity.java

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am trying to learn android programming by google's android programming course (android studio) in udacity.
The problem is I do not have "PlaceholderFragment" class in my MainActivity.java.
I only have MainActivity class in this file.
Could anyone help me please?

Edit: 
my MainActivity.java is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code. This is the only way we can help you and it shows effort. I noticed you have been a member for a long time. Please read the tutorial @ http://stackoverflow.com/tour . You gain few rep points by reading.

Comment: You should clarify what you want to do. If you just need a Fragemt, there are multiple easy way to do this. It might be possible that Android Studio automatically added a Fragment called PlaceholderFragment in the past.

Comment: It is present in `MainActivityFragment.java` with name present in your `main_activity.xml`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced the same problem when using Udacity course "Developing Android Apps: Android Fundamentals". The Udacity videos are old > 9 months and since android studios is always updating, the newer version of android studio does not provide an inner class for the fragment anymore. Instead android studio generates a separate class containing a fragment. But, no problem.

Go to the tab of  Lesson 1: "Using the Sunshine Github Repository" and open the link: Udacity Sunshine repository

Download the branch : "1.01_hello_world" and import the contents into android studios. You will have the "PlaceholderFragment" class within the MainActivity.java and then you can continue the lessons at Udacity

Answer (score 1):

You need to read a good webpage. I recommend reading and studying code from Google's @ [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).
Code snippets from the webpage:

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}

ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Note: `ExampleFragment` could be your "PlaceholderFragment".

Answer (score 0):

Just delete your code succeeding your package name in the MainActivity.java file and replace it with this one below.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider briefly explaining why this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, right after I put the "ForecastFragment" class into it's own file.

What solved the problem for me was to go build - clean project. After doing that, it built just fine.

Perhaps there are some old build files that look for placeholderFragment?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I tried to figure out how to work with the new structure. I put the code inside MainActivityFragment.java, inside the method `onCreateView`, since this is the new approach. It worked for me. 
Take a look of my final code:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container);

        ArrayList<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<>();

        weekForecast.add("Today - Sunny - 88/63");
        weekForecast.add("Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/40");
        weekForecast.add("Weds - Cloudy - 72/63");
        weekForecast.add("Thurs - Asteroids - 75/65");
        weekForecast.add("Fri - Heavy Rain - 65/56");
        weekForecast.add("Sat - HELP TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 60/51");
        weekForecast.add("Sun - Sunny - 80/68");

        mForecastAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weekForecast);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```